# WebServer using AT Command iin STM32

Tags: stm32cubeide

I'm having trouble using STM32 to bind to the Webserver via the AT Command command. Connecting to the Webserver is fine, but the problem is that the site only runs a few times, the AT+CIPSEND command has a problem, data sent to ESP is 1 character error causing the data response process to be ERROR. Everyone shows me how to fix it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt4vv.png)
This is the problem that I encountered, the webserver run a few times, the AT+CIPSEND sending process is faulty at the letter E. I don't know what the fault is.

Comment: Please share the exact function and string you're using to send the command.